# How to get an Integer value from <s:select> String

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

Here is my DAO:

```
public ReportType getByName(String type) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        ReportType rptype2 = em.find(ReportType.class, type);

        return rptype2;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        em.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is my Action:

```
ReportDAO dao = new ReportDAO();
    List<ReportType> reportType = dao.show();
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ReportType reportType1 : reportType) {
        list.add(reportType1.getName());
    }
    ReportTypeDAO rpDAO = new ReportTypeDAO();
    reporttype = rpDAO.getByName(type);
```

Here is my jsp:

```xml
 <h3>Type: <s:select list="list" name="type"></s:select>
```

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Report_Type](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
```

When i submit, i receive a record in String format (Name), but i want to get this record ID. 
Is there any solution?

Comment: `list.add(reportType1.getName());`. You are adding the `name` to this list. You should be adding the `id` instead.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I think that the OP will need both name **and** id in their list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `listKey` and `listValue`:

```xml
<s:select list = "list" 
       listKey = "id"
     listValue = "name"
          name = "type" />
```

Read more on [the documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the id and name in your select using listKey and listValue.

```
<s:select label="My Label"
       name="name"
       list="list"
       listKey="id"
       listValue="name"
      "/>
```